# Why can't Application Verifier find memory leaks?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, application-verifier

I'm using Windows 10 Application Verifier, x64 version 10.0.10586. It has all the "Basics" checkboxes ticked, including "Leak". Application Verifier curiously is implementing a page protected heap for the memory, as the malloc call returns memory at the end of a page.

DLL code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void LeakMemory()
{
    malloc(1);
    VirtualAlloc(nullptr, 4096, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
}
```

main code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

int main(int, char**)
{
    //_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);

    HMODULE h = LoadLibraryW(L"DLLProject.dll");
    void(*pLeakMemory)() = reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(GetProcAddress(h, "LeakMemory"));
    pLeakMemory();
    FreeLibrary(h);

    printf("bye\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output is as follows:

```
Page heap: pid 0xFE8: page heap enabled with flags 0x3.
AVRF: ConsoleApplication4.exe: pid 0xFE8: flags 0x81643027: application verifier enabled
bye
The program '[11172] TestProject.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

App verifier fails to report either of the leaks.

If I enable the _CrtDbgFlag call then verifies that in fact the malloc leaked by also printing this on app shutdown:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{74} normal block at 0x0000015C0979EFF0, 1 bytes long.
 Data: < > CD 
Object dump complete.
```

Why doesn't Application Verifier work? It also fails to find leaks if I allocate memory in main() instead of a DLL, but I think that's a known limitation of it.

Comment: `malloc` is a C runtime function, thus it is the compiler's heap manager that is responsible for this.  The `malloc` is not a Win32 API allocation function, which I would suspect ApplicationVerifier would be able to track.  If you changed that call from `malloc(1)` to `GlobalAlloc` or similar call without calling `GlobalFree`, does AppVerifier detect that leak?